# Adding names on mouseover

Tags: r, networkd3

Im trying to visualize the name of the nodes in a `forceNetwork` from [networkd3](/questions/tagged/networkd3).

```
forceNetwork(Links = linksF, Nodes = Nodes2,
         Source = "source", Target = "target",
         Value = "value", NodeID = "name", Group = "group",
         Nodesize = "size", linkDistance = 350,
         opacity = 0.8, fontSize = 30, linkColour = "#2B2033",
         radiusCalculation = "d.nodesize+6",
         linkWidth = JS("function(d) { return (d.value/3); }"),
         legend = TRUE, zoom = TRUE)
```

Currently the name of a node is shown at mouseover, is it possible that all neighbors are shown at mouseover instead?

If not, how can i show all node names at all time?

Answer (score 0):

use the `opacityNoHover = 1` argument... as stated in the help file "opacityNoHover: numeric value of the opacity proportion for node labels text when the mouse is not hovering over them."